# XSD Required Elements with specific child elements (Multiple Definitions with different types)

Tags: xsd

All,  I have an XML doc which I don't control for which I need to create an xsd to validate.  The XML doc has multiple transaction types, some of which are required a specific number of times, and some aren't. the parent element is simply <transaction>, the child element can be either a <ControlTransaction> or a <RetailTransaction>.  The issue is that I need to require a <transaction> to exists with a <ControlTransaction> with a <ReasonCode> element having a value of "Register Open" and another with a value of "Register Close" as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RegisterDay xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:cp="urn:register"> 

<Transaction>
    <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
    <ControlTransaction>
        <ReasonCode>Register Open</ReasonCode>
    </ControlTransaction>
</Transaction>

<Transaction>
    <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
    <RetailTransaction>
        ...stuff..
        <Total>9.99</Total>
    </RetailTransaction>
</Transaction>

<Transaction>
    <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
    <ControlTransaction>
        <ReasonCode>Register Close</ReasonCode>
    </ControlTransaction>
</Transaction>

</RegisterDay>
```

My best attempt is to use types in my schema, but get "Elements with the same name and same scope must have the same type".  I don't know how to get around this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
        xmlns:cp="urn:register" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="RegisterDay">     
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Transaction" type="TransactionRegisterOpen_type"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Transaction" type="RetailTransaction_type"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Transaction" type="TransactionRegisterClose_type"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>       

    <xs:simpleType name="RegisterOpen_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Register Open"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="RegisterClose_type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Register Close"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="TransactionRegisterOpen_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="ControlTransaction">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="ReasonCode" type="RegisterOpen_type"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   

    <xs:complexType name="TransactionRegisterClose_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="ControlTransaction">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="ReasonCode" type="RegisterClose_type"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   

    <xs:complexType name="RetailTransaction_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="ControlTransaction">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="Total" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>           

</xs:schema>
```

Has anyone run into this and/or have any suggestions?  I'm pretty much stumped.

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph ?

Comment: Istao, Thanks for commenting.  My tags were not showing.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with enumeration ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:cp="urn:register" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:register">

<xs:element name="RegisterDay">     
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element 
              minOccurs="1" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded" 
              name="Transaction" 
              type="cp:TypeTransaction"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>       

<xs:complexType name="TypeTransaction">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="RetailTransaction"/>
          <xs:element name="ControlTransaction">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ReasonCode">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:enumeration value="Register Open"/> 
                      <xs:enumeration value="Register Close"/> 
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>  
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>           

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Istao: Thank you for the response.  However, this does not require that both of these ControlTransactions (Register Open and Register Close) be present.  It only limits the ReasonCode to these values.

Comment: Is it possible to say _register open is the first, register close the last_, or something like that ?

Comment: No.  I tried to simplify the XML to be as clear as possible, but there are other transaction elements before and after the register open/close transactions (time card punches, store open/close, etc.).